# Challenging the Node syntax

Tags: c, data-structures, syntax, linked-list, nodes

The following is a syntax, part of linked list in C programming language

```
struct tag-name
{
   type member1;
   type member2;
   .......
   .......
   struct tag-name *next;
 };
```

Why do we have to again write struct tag-name before the pointer variable next.  Why can we not use void *next or int *next or something like that??

Comment: You can put whatever you want. But if you want a linked list of nodes, the next thing better be a node, no?

Comment: You don't have to if you `typedef struct tag-name somename;` before. Then just use the `somename`. And this is not a part of the language but kind of design pattern.

Comment: The posted code does not define the struct and there is no tag. I see only forward declaration and block of code

Comment: This isn't code. Can you include something that is valid C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the typical illustration of a linked list:

```
node                node                node
+------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+
| data | next | --> | data | next | --> | data | next | --> ...
+------+------+     +------+------+     +------+------+
```

Each item in the list is a *node* of some type, and that node contains a `next` member that explicitly points to the next *node* in the list.  In C, that typically translates to a `struct` type like

```
struct node 
{
  T data; // for some type T
  struct node *next;
};
```

IOW, each `struct node` has a `next` member that points to another object of type `struct node` - not `int`, not `void`, etc., which is why we don't declare `next` as an `int *`, or a `void *`, or whatever.

However...

Depending on how you implement your list, you *can* use something other than a `struct node *` as your `next` item.  Normally when we implement a list, we dynamically allocate each node using `malloc` as we need it.  However, if you know that your list will never get bigger than some known, reasonably small value, you can set aside an *array* of `struct node` as your "heap", and your `next` member can be an array index value:

```
struct node
{
  T data;
  int next; // holds the *index* of the next element
} heap[SOME_SIZE];
```

You then initialize your "heap" so that each element explicitly points to the next in the array:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE-1; i++ )
{
  heap[i].next = i+1;
}
heap[SOME_SIZE-1].next = -1; // use -1 to indicate "null"
```

Now, all you need is a couple of integers, one to point to the first available element in the array, and the other to point to the head of your list:

```
int avail = 0;  // initially points to the first element in the "heap"
int head  = -1; // initially "null"
```

"Allocating" a node then just becomes a matter of finding the first free node in the "heap":

```
int node = avail;         // get the index of the next available node in the "heap";
avail = heap[avail].next; // update avail to point to the next available node
```

"Freeing" a node just means adding that index back to the head of the `avail` list:

```
heap[node].next = avail; // set this node point to the first free element
avail = node;            // make this node the first free element;
```

Remember, `node` and `avail` are not node objects, they're simply indices into an array of node objects.

We typically don't do it this way because it's conceptually simpler for `next` to point to another `struct node` object directly, rather than be an index into an array.  We can still use a fixed-sized array as our "heap", we just use the address of each element instead of its index.

Answer (score 1):

for a linked list the `next` entry (or whatever its named) must point to the next node. In your case the node type is `tag-name`.

so you need `<type> next;`

in C (different for c++) the way you ask for a pointer to a struct called x is to do `struct x *`. Hence the code you see that is confusing / upsetting you. Can you simplify it? Yes you can. C has `typedef`. You can do

`typedef struct tag-name node;`

and now you can have

```
struct tag-name
{
   type member1;
   type member2;
   .......
   .......
   node *next;
 };
```

You ask, can I have `void* next`. Yes but why do it? You will have to keep casting that pointer to a pointer to the struct (the compiler does not know implicitly what it points to), also a reader of the code will be surprised because they expect the next pointer to be a pointer to a node.

You ask can it be `int next`. No it cannot, the next object is a node, not an int